# Unix sed command - global replacement is not working

Tags: shell, unix, awk, sed, scripting

I have scenario where we want to replace multiple double quotes to single quotes between the data, but as the  input data is separated with `"comma"` delimiter and all column data is enclosed with double quotes `""` got an issue and the same explained below:

The sample data looks like this:

```
"int","","123","abd"""sf123","top"
```

So, the output would be:

```
"int","","123","abd"sf123","top"
```

tried below approach to get the resolution, but only first occurrence is working, not sure what is the issue??

```
sed -ie 's/,"",/,"NULL",/g;s/""/"/g;s/,"NULL",/,"",/g' inputfile.txt
```

1. replacing all --->  from    ,"",  to    ,"NULL",
2. replacing all multiple occurrences of  --->  from   """ or "" or """"  to  " (single occurrence)
3. replacing 1 step changes back to original  --->  from   ,"NULL",  to  ,"",

But, only first occurrence is getting changed and remaining looks same as below:

If input is :

```
"int","","","123","abd"""sf123","top"
```

the output is coming as:

```
"int","","NULL","123","abd"sf123","top"
```

But, the output should be:

```
"int","","","123","abd"sf123","top"
```

Comment: Does it have to be `sed` only solution or you are fine with other unix tools also like perl/awk?

Comment: Matches can’t overlap, so your comma can only appear in one of those two adjacent matches. To be honest you should really make use of a proper CSV parsing library.

Comment: Can you just use: `sed 's/"""/"/g' file`

Comment: Ya we can try with other commands as well.

Comment: @anubhava  the command you gave will work , but there is chance in the input file the data comes as *"123"""""abcs"* aslo in such case it would be *"123"abcs"*.

Comment: Proper CSV uses double double-quotes for embedding literal quotes in a value. You'd want the output do be `"int","","123","abd""sf123","top"` with 2 double-quotes in the 4th field. https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc4180#section-2

Comment: `"abd"""sf123"` (with 3 `"`s in the middle) is invalid input by any CSV "standard" for the same reason @glennjackman just gave about your desired output. You need to fix whatever is creating that input rather than trying to deal with it later - who knows what else will be wrong with it?

Comment: The reasons to quote a field in CSV are a) if it contains `,` or b) if it contains newline. Given that a quoted field can contain `,`s, the reason a quote has to be doubled inside a quoted is field is so that you can't have a single field like `"this","that"` as that'd be indistinguishable from 2 separate fields, and instead you'd have `"this"",""that"` as the single field. You should include more rainy-day cases in your example as that one sunny-day case isn't adequate to test a potential solution against.

Answer (score 3):

You may try this `perl` with a lookahead:

```bash
perl -pe 's/("")+(?=")//g' file

"int","","123","abd"sf123","top"
"int","","","123","abd"sf123","top"
"123"abcs"
```

Where input is:

```bash
cat file

"int","","123","abd"""sf123","top"
"int","","","123","abd"""sf123","top"
"123"""""abcs"
```

**Breakup:**

- `("")+`: Match 1+ **pairs** of double quotes
- `(?=")`: If those pairs are followed by a single `"`

Comment: That would convert `"foo",""","bar"` to `"foo",","bar"` which I expect wouldn't be desirable.

Answer (score 2):

Using `sed`

```
$ sed -E 's/(,"",)?"+(",)?/\1"\2/g' input_file
"int","","123","abd"sf123","top"
"int","","NULL","123","abd"sf123","top"
"int","","","123","abd"sf123","top"
```

Answer (score 2):

In `awk` with your shown samples please try following `awk` code. Written and tested in GNU `awk`, should work in any version of `awk`.

```
awk '
BEGIN{ FS=OFS="," }
{
  for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){
    if($i!~/^""$/){
       gsub(/"+/,"\"",$i)
    }
  }
}
1
'  Input_file
```

***Explanation:*** Simple explanation would be, setting field separator and output field separator as `,` for all the lines of Input_file. Then traversing through each field of line, if a field is NOT NULL then Globally replacing all 1 or more occurrences of `"` with single occurrence of `"`. Then printing the line.

Comment: That would convert `"foo",""","bar"` to `"foo",","bar"` which I expect wouldn't be desirable.

Answer (score 1):

With `sed` you could repeat 1 or more times sets of `""` using a group followed by matching a single `"`

Then in the replacement use a single `"`

```
sed -E 's/("")+"/"/g' file
```

For this content

```
$ cat file
"int","","123","abd"""sf123","top"
"int","","","123","abd"""sf123","top"
"123"""""abcs"
```

The output is

```
"int","","123","abd"sf123","top"
"int","","","123","abd"sf123","top"
"123"abcs"
```

Comment: That would convert `"foo",""","bar"` to `"foo",","bar"` which I expect wouldn't be desirable.

Comment: @EdMorton I see your point here, if that is not desirable then I will delete the answer. Lets wait for some feedback..if any

Answer (score 0):

```
sed s'@"""@"@' file
```

That works.  I will demonstrate another method though, which you may also find useful in other situations.

#!/bin/sh -x

```
cat > ed1 <<EOF
3s/"""/"/
wq
EOF

cp file stack
cat stack | tr ',' '\n' > f2
ed -s f2 < ed1
cat f2 | tr '\n' ',' > stack
rm -v ./f2
rm -v ./ed1
```

The point of this is that if you have a big csv record all on one line, and you want to edit a specific field, then if you know the field number, you can convert all the commas to carriage returns, and use the field number as a line number to either substitute, append after it, or insert before it with Ed; and then re-convert back to csv.

Comment: That would convert `"foo",""","bar"` to `"foo",","bar"` which I expect wouldn't be desirable.